# Adding a querystring parameter to all request made by a WebClient

Tags: c#

I have extended the `WebClient` class and overriden the `GetWebRequest` method. Is there any way to add a querystring parameter to all my requests in this method?

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;

    if (webRequest != null)
    {

    }
}
```

I've tried modifying the `address` but it doesn't seem to help. And the `webRequest.Address` has no setter.

Comment: why not add query string when you actually create the `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: @Mayank Because I don't want to do it each time I create a new request.

Comment: Can you modify the address in the call to the base constructor?

Comment: @PhilipPittle The address differs for each new request made. It's not static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your sample and was able to modify the address in the `GetWebRequest` method by passing a new `Uri` to `base.GetWebRequest()`:

```
public class CustomWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var newUrl = address.OriginalString;

        if (newUrl.Contains("?"))
            newUrl += "&";
        else
            newUrl += "?";

        newUrl += "MyCustomParam=value";


        return base.GetWebRequest(new Uri(newUrl));
    }
}
```

Then if I call `new CustomWebClient().DownloadData("http://stackoverflow.com")` the actual url (as seen by fiddler) is https://stackoverflow.com/?MyCustomParam=value